# Adding more levels in table view and creating some folding animation will it be a weight-age to the app in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Before announcing this question as duplicate or closed i want to clarify one doubt. I want to make slide pane in left side with some menu it will contain totally three level's in table view every menu will have two sub menu and sub menu will have sub sub menu and also i want to add folding animation while i call the left view which contains the table view. So whether it is bad approach to put all in single view? Whether it will create more weight-age to the app?? pls need some help in this.thanks in advance!!

Comment: You are on a right track, this is the correct way to implement tree views in iOS.

Comment: It won be a weight age to the App? because table view already having sub menu and sub sub menu and it is not root view it is just left view like face book and also while i call left view am using folding animation using some library file. So it won be a problem by putting all things in same view??